# How to limit the number of cells UITableview displays?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Im using a tableview to display some information in a quiz app that Im working on. My question is how do i make the tableview only show the number of cells that I need. Ive set the number of rows delegate method like this:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 5;
}
```

but at the bottom of the table view are empty cells that are not needed. If I set the tableview style to grouped I get 5 cells and no empty ones below them. Ive seen that other people have done this but cant seem to work it out. I was wondering if they have somehow added a custom view to the table footer to cancel the empty cells out?

Any ideas or help appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear as to whether you want to avoid using the grouped style or have problems using it?

Comment: I dont have any issues implementing either grouped on standard UITableView's. Im trying to say if i use grouped and set the number of rows per section to 5 when i run the app i see 5 rows and thats it, just 5 rows. If on the other hand I use the standard table view and set the number of rows to 5 rows, I see that I get my 5 rows but then below them are an additional number of empty rows that have no content and are not needed but are put there just to fill the screen up.

Answer (score 15):

If you do want to keep the separator, you could insert a dummy footer view.  This will limit the tableview to only show the amount of cells you returned in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

In swift:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Comment: Nice one. Just make sure not to have a fixed height set for that table view or the additional footer view may push things further down under the table view (even though it's just a dummy).

Comment: In Swift 3:

self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

Answer (score 2):

A much nicer method which doesn't require cell resizing is to turn off the default separator (set the style to none) and then have a separator line in the cell itself.

Comment: So this would involve creating a custom cell in IB or would i have to add a seperator into the cell programmatically?

Comment: You could do either. I generally subclass UITableViewCell but you can add a subview to the contentview of a normal UITableViewCell. IB or code is purely down to how you prefer to work...

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, how to show only separators for the cells that contain data.

What I did was the following:

1. Disable separators for the whole tableView. You can do that in the
   inspector for the tableview in Interface builder or by calling
   `[yourTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];`.
2. Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you populate your tableview with cells create a new `UIView` and set it as a subview to the cell. Have the background of this view lightgray and slightly transparent. You can do that with the following:

   ```
   UIView *separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:
                                           (0, cell.frame.size.height-1, 
                                              cell.frame.size.width, 1)];
   [separatorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
   [separatorView setAlpha:0.8f];
   [cell addSubView:separatorView];
   ```

   The width of this view is 1 pixel which is the same as the default separator, it runs the length of the cell, at the bottom.

Since `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called as often as you have specified in `numberOfRowsInSection` these subviews will only be created for the cells that possess data and should have a separator.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me - I had extra empty rows at the bottom of the screen on an iphone 5 -

In my case I needed 9 rows

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tabelView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    return self.tableView.frame.size.height / 9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement *heightForRowAtIndexPath:* and compute the correct height to only show 5 cells on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Are you always going to have 5 rows?  If it's a dynamic situation you should set the number of rows according to the datasource of the tableview.  For example:

```
return [postListData count];
```

This returns the count of the records in the array holding the content.

The tableview is only going to display the number of rows and sections that you tell it to. If you're always going to have just a single section, DON'T implement the method below.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
```

Without this the tableview will only have 1 section.  With it, as you would imagine, you can specify the number of sections.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite Simple. Just set the size of the popover like this:
self.optionPickerPopOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
Certainly you can adjust the size (200,200) depending upon the size of contents and number if rows.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be to shrink tableView size. I.e. 5 cells 20 points each gives 100.0f, setting height to 100.0f will cause only 5 rows will be visible. Another way would be to return more rows, but rows 6,7 and so would be some views with alpha 0, but that seems cumbersome. Have you tried to return some clerColor view as footerView?

Answer (score 0):

I think u can try changing the frame of the table view, if you want to adjust with the number of cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`[table setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height*[list count])];`

height refers to height of the cell

Answer (score 0):

As Nyx0uf said, limiting the size of the cell can accomplish this.  For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tabelView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat result;

    result = 100;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

implement these two methods in your UITableViewController:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    }
    return nil;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, these codes are telling tableview that you don't need to render the seperator line for me anymore, so that it looks the empty cells won't be displayed(in fact , the empty cell can not be selected too)